# How to disable GTK Drag'n Drop?

Tags: c++, c, gtk

How to complete disable Drag'n Drop from a GtkEntry ?

Comment: I wish I knew. I hate drag-and-drop in text areas. Makes it impossible to correct off-by-one mouse selection errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd discovered that if you set the property `gtk-dnd-drag-threshold` to a value larger than the screen size, it will block the DnD for the whole application.